# UIActivityViewController 撮影した写真のSNS投稿時のクラッシュについて

Tags: swift, xcode

カメラで撮影した写真をsnsに投稿するアプリを練習しています。

取得した画像をツイッター等シェアしようとすると、クラッシュして投稿出来ません。

webで答えを探していたのですが、解決出来ず・・助けて頂けないでしょうか。
コードでエラーは出ていないので、設定の問題？？

```
 //SNSへ投稿するボタンをタップで実行
    @IBAction func SNSButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //表示画像をアンラップしてシェア画像として取り出し
        if let shareImage = pictureImage.image{
            //UIActivityViewControllerに渡す配列を作成
            let shareItems = [shareImage]
            //UIActivityViewControllerにシェア画像を渡す
            let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil )
           //ipadで落ちてしまう対策
            controller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
            //UIActivityViewControllerを表示
            present(controller,animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

エラー内容

```
SLRemoteComposeViewController: (this may be harmless) viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}
```

Comment: iOS 11でSNS連携機能がバッサリ削除されて以降、「ツイッター等シェア」はiOSの標準状態ではできなくなっているはずです。どのようなアプリを入れて試されていますでしょうか? それらのアプリ(正確に言うとアプリと一緒についてくる機能拡張ですが)が最新のiOSに対応していない(あるいは単純にバグがある)可能性もあります。

Comment: 本の例題ですので、カメラを起動して写真を撮る、その画像を取得し、SNSボタン、activityVCで画像をシェアする。だけのアプリです。 何度か試していたらツイッターはシェアできました！ Facebookはシェアアイコン押したらクラッシュ、LINEも送信ボタンを押すとクラッシュします。調べてみるとFacebookとLINEは個別の設定があるようなので、個別でボタン設定したほうがよさそうですかね…

Comment: テスト用デバイスにツイッターアプリとFacebookアプリとLINEアプリをインストールした状態でテストしている、と言うことでしょうか?

Comment: 仰る通りです。 全てアプリはインストールしてあります。

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます。練習用なら、問題ないとは思いますが、まっさらのiOS 11以上のデバイスでは、「activityVCで画像をシェアする。だけのアプリ」では、各SNSには連携できませんのでご注意ください。で、それらのアプリをインストールすると同時に機能拡張(Share Extension)がインストールされるので、それによりactivityVCによる画像のシェアが行えるようになるわけですが、一部のSNSの機能拡張ではこれがうまく動かないと言うバグが報告されていたことがあります。とりあえずは各アプリは最新化されていますでしょう

Comment: とりあえずアプリは最新にしています。

Comment: 了解しました。残念ながらSNSアプリの(機能拡張の)バグなのか設定の問題なのかは、今までの情報だけではよくわからないですね。ただ、あなたのアプリのインストール先の状態にもよることなので、各SNSの公式SDKを入手して個別にあなたのアプリから投稿できるようにしてしまった方が確実かもしれません。または自分で3つのSNSに同時に投稿できるようなShare Extensionを書いちゃうとか。あれこれお聞きしたのに、あまり役に立ちそうなことがかけなくて申し訳ありません。

Comment: いえいえ。ありがとうございます、ご相談に乗って頂き感謝してます。色々と試行錯誤してみます。

Comment: 何か新情報があったら(場合によってはなくても文言を訂正するなどして)ご質問内容を修正すると、アクティブリストの上位にくるので、私なんかよりはるかに詳しい人にこの質問を見つけてもらえる可能性が高まります。試行錯誤と並行しながらやってみて下さい。うまい解決方法が見つかるといいですね。